# AUIOClient_StartIO failing while attempting to play out in background

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, ios7, voip

I am facing the same error in Audio unit in iOS7

"2013-10-14 18:24:29.262 QchatDLA[946:9a1f] 18:24:29.262 ERROR: [0x655d000] AURemoteIO.cpp:1207: Start: AUIOClient_StartIO failed (-16981)"

Mine is a VoIP app and i was attempting to receive audio while in back ground. This is perfectly working in iOS 6.1.4 while its not working on iOS 7.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also met the same problem with iOS 7.0.2, but when I upgraded to 7.0.3 this morning, the problem was resolved and sound came back again.

Thus my solution to this problem is to upgrade your device to 7.0.3 as this seems like a bug of iOS 7.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error. I play audio in the background (for a Push to talk application). I was trying to show a red status bar (using a fake audioUnit enabling mic) at the top of the screen when there is an incoming PTT call. 
The code worked well on iOS6 , but gave the error AURemoteIO.cpp:1207: Start: AUIOClient_StartIO failed (-16981) on iOS7.

The issue that I found is I had set audio session category as AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient in iOS6. 
When I set the session category as AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, problem got fixed.

Comment: same scenariao is happening with me I also used AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, If i use  AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord it reduces my audio volume.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting enough, when your app is in background and trying to access inputNode, even if you try to remove a tap, engine will raise this error and won't allow you to start it.